# What happens to setInterval in react-native after app is in background?

Tags: react-native, timer

I have setup a timer to refresh the screen every 5 minutes.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.handle = setInterval(() => this.props.refreshData(), 300000);
  this.props.refreshData();
}
```

In componentWillUnmount, I clear the handle.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.handle);
}
```

What happens to the timer when the app moves to background? Will it be paused automatically? Or will it continue to run even if the app is in the background? Thanks.

Comment: As I see, it will pause automatically with `react native ios` but not sure in `android`. In case it not run in `android` you can use `AppState` to set it again while app run from idle mode.

Answer (score 2):

Android will not allow you to set an interval or timeout longer than 2 minutes. You should get a warning about it on Android, and I believe in production the app will "crash" when state is changed to the background.

Comment: thanks. reduced the timeout for android. it did not crash though.

Comment: @vijayst I don't think it's a full on crash, just reboots your app if I remember correctly. You tried the 5 minute interval in a release build?

Comment: I reduced timeout before trying it. I will check logs if it is restarting with an interval of 1 min.